# Get list of existing QShortcuts

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to create various objects with associated keyboard shortcuts. The following code works fine. However, it doesn't prevent multiple objects from **being assigned the same shortcut keys**.

I'd like the `create_shortcut` function to check if there are existing shortcuts with the same keys and return an error if there are.

I've looked over the [documentation for QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html) but haven't found any way to list existing shortcuts.

Any idea how to do this?

```py
class MyClass(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent, shortcut_keys: str):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.create_shortcut(shortcut_keys)

    def create_shortcut(self, shortcut_keys) -> None:
        parent = self.parent()
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(shortcut_keys), parent)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.do_stuff)
    
    def do_stuff(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html) inherits from QObject, meaning that it is always shown in the list of children of the parent for which it was created.

Assuming that the shortcuts have always been created with a parent, just use [`findChildren(className)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren):

```py
def create_shortcut(self, shortcut_keys) -> None:
    seq = QKeySequence(shortcut_keys)
    for other in self.parent().findChildren(QShortcut):
        if seq == other.key():
            # already exists, ignore
            return

    # create new shortcut
    shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(shortcut_keys), parent)
    shortcut.activated.connect(self.do_stuff)
```

<sup>Note: creating persistent instance attributes is pointless whenever those attributes will be most certainly overwritten.</sup>

Alternatively, just create a list as instance attribute, append new shortcuts to it and always check for them before creating others.

Comment: Excellent. This worked. Can you suggest a way to extend the search to the entire application, and not just the widget?

Comment: @AndrewPlowright [`QApplication.topLevelWidgets()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets) and then use `findChildren()` with each of them (by default it searches recursively).

Comment: Thanks! I also needed to do this for `findChildren(QAction)`, since some of the app's shortcuts were stored in those as well